# Having trouble dealing with conditional statement inside React/JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to correctly set-up conditional statements inside my JSX. The dictate if certain elements should appear on the screen or not.

To dive deeper into detail, here is my code snippet. I have two elements, the `<p>` tags and `<Graph>`. I would like for the `<p>` tags to show up when `stockCount` ===  0. When stockCount does not equal 0, then I would like the `<graph>` component to show, instead of the `<p>`'s

```js
              <Grid>
              {(!stockCount || stockCount === 0) &&
                <p>
                    Your have zero stocks...
                </p>
                }
                {stockCount && stockCount > 0 &&
                  <Graph/>
                }
              </Grid>
```

I'm not getting any errors to work from, so I am a little confused on why the above does not work.

Comment: What kind of error you got ? Logic error or compile error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code duplicates the conditions unnecessarily. You could simplify your code with a ternary operation, like so:

```
render() {
    return (
     <Grid>
       {
        !stockCount ? <p>You have zero stocks</p> : <Graph />
       }
     </Grid>
     )
  }
```

Also note that you don't need to test for `!stockCount || stockCount === 0` because both evaluate to falsey values (`undefined` and `0`), so they're always going to return `false`. Of course, in the case that you're dealing with numerical values and you don't want 0 to be a falsey value, you have to write code to account for that, but it's not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the count and apply ternary operator.

```
<Grid>
{stockCount && stockCount > 0 ?
  <Graph/>:
    <p>
     Your have zero stocks...
    </p>
}
</Grid>
```